# How to use the response object of AFHTTPRequestOperation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want to use the response object of AFHTTPRequestOperation outside of the success block. Here is my code below:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my_url"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"user" password:@"pass" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    [op setCredential:credential];
    op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        for(NSDictionary *item in responseObject){
          [arr addObject:item];
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:op];
    NSLog(@"%@",arr);// here arr getting null or empty
```

I am getting the response object fine but if I want to use responseObject outside of the success block then object gets null.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You can store it in a local variable or in a property, depending on your needs.

Comment: This isn't about AFHTPPRequestOperation, it's about blocks. You should start reading here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html . 
When your program reaches the line where you log the array, the loop where the array is filled (inside the block) wasn't already executed. That's why the array is empty.

Comment: I have added changed mutable array  like here __block NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; but still the array is empty , what should I do now?

Comment: Google synchronous vs asynchronous operations. You expect this to act synchronously, while it is in fact asynchronous. Calling method returns before the block inside is executes, so your "arr" at the end of calling method will always be empty.

Comment: Then what is the solution so that arr array can't be empty?